# View image in JSP page from MySQL using Struts 2

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsp, struts2

I have a button to pick up the image and put it in MySQL database. After this, I want that the image will be showed in the same page. I'm new to Struts2 and I don't know how to go on now.

This is my class `Registrazione.java`:

```
public String visualizzaimg() throws SQLException, IOException {
    Connessione();    // DB connection method
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Immagine FROM Utenti WHERE Username = ?");
    pstmt.setString(1,username);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    fin = rs.getBinaryStream("Immagine");
    byte[] b = new byte[fin.available()];
    fin.read(b);
    }
    return "success";
}
```

This is my `struts.xml` file:

```
<action name="visualizzaimg" class="Model.Registrazione" method="visualizzaimg">
<result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
        <param name="inputName">fin</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${fileName}</param> /* Not sure if i've understood what i have to put here.. */
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

And this is my `LoginRiuscito.jsp` page:

```
<s:form action="carica" id="carica" style="display:none" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:textfield id="username" name="username" type="hidden"></s:textfield>
    <s:file id="carica" name="caricaimg" accept="image/*"></s:file>
    <s:submit value="Carica" ></s:submit>
</s:form>
<s:form action="visualizzaimg" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:textfield id="username" name="username" type="hidden"></s:textfield>
    <img src="">  //i don't know what i have to put in src..
    <s:submit value="Visualizza"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to write url to the `<img>` tag. The url should map an action that streaming data to the response.

```
<img src="<s:url action='visualizzaimg'/>">
```

The action needs to return a `stream` result, for this purpose it should provide a getter for `InputStream`. The default input name for the input stream is `inputStream`, so we will use it.

```
private InputStream inputStream;

public ImputStream getInputStream(){
  return inputStream;
}

public String visualizzaimg() throws SQLException, IOException {
    Connessione();    // DB connection method
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Immagine FROM Utenti WHERE Username = ?");
    pstmt.setString(1,username);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
      inputStream = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
    }
    return "success";
}
```

Now to configure result

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
   <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
</result>
```

Comment: It does work!! But can you explain this? Why you put 1 in getBinaryStream?  `inputStream = rs.getBinaryStream(1);`

Comment: Because [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28int%29) method uses a column index parameter of type `int`.

Comment: ... and you can find on the page that parameters a counting from 1.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's possible to view the image in the same jsp page? Because when i click on 'Visualizza' button it opens another action  called 'visualizzaimg.action' with the image

Comment: It should be another action that returns JSP in the result.