# How to dispaly multiple images using struts2 and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2

In my jsp

```
 <img src="<s:url value="image" />" />
```

in xml

```
<action name="image"
            class="com.sms.UserImagedisplay">
</action>
```

in controller class, getting image from database

byte[] itemImage = null;

```
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
for (userimage usersimages : getusersimages) {
            itemImage = usersimages.getActualimage();

        }

try {
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                out.write(itemImage);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

this code works fine for single image but how to display multiple image

i tried this code but its displays only one image

```
List<byte[]>  itemImage = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

for (byte[] bs : itemImage) {
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
        try {

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bs);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Even through size of list is two i am not able to display more than 1 image and any help will be appreciable

Answer (score 1):

Every image / file must have it's own data stream. Thus you could modify your action and jsp to something like this:

```
<s:url action="image" id="imageUrl">
    <s:param name="index">0</s:param>
</s:url>
<img src="<s:property value='%{imageUrl}'>"/>
```

Your action have to accept this `index`-parameter and you can select the image from your array.

```
class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private int index;

    public String execute() {
        ...
        byte[] bs = itemImage[index];
        ...
    }
    //getter/setter
}
```

Just a side node: You are using struts, consider using the struts stream result ([doc](https://struts.apache.org/docs/stream-result.html)) instead of manipulating the the `OutputStream` directly. Here is a similar question with an answer how to use it: [View image in JSP page from MySQL using Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342455/view-image-in-jsp-page-from-mysql-using-struts-2)

Comment: (doc) i read this document but here image is stored in filepath but i have stored image in byte[]

Comment: Please read and think before you respond multiple times. The doc was just a node to you about struts functionality and the question I linked there is an example with a stream result and an byte array. The `index` var is the var you are getting from calling the action with somehost/image?index=1

Comment: okk sorry if my comment annoyed you and i am new to programming anyhow thanks for your response